# How to submit a file upload asynchronously using jquery-file-upload plugin

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use blue-imp's jQuery file upload plugin to manage file uploads on my website.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

The demo implementation includes a button inside of a form. When this button is clicked it initiates a file upload of all files in the upload queue (done asynchronously).

I want to simulate this behavior, but with a button *outside* of the form.

Right now, whenever a file is added to the dropzone it is immediately uploaded. I want instead for it to be simulated with a click, done async, and with a button outside of the form. Is this possible?  I just need to know how in JavaScript I can trigger a file upload of everything in the file upload queue. Thanks!

Current implementation (called when a file is added to the dropzone):

```
 add: ƒ(e, data) {
             var jqXHR = data.submit();
          }
```

Comment: is it possible? i'm sure it is... you'd just need to trigger the forms' submit event when the button is clicked. Why did you add the function to `add:` if you don't want it to happen when a file is added? why is that part relevant?

Comment: @KevinB It's showing what I'm currently doing to upload a file asychronously. I have no problem using jQuery to get the form, and then call submit(). The problem is that its not asynchronous and it doesn't upload all files in the file upload queue.